# Installing pyperclip for Python issues

Tags: python, pip

[image: Error message image]

Following the 'Automate the Boring Stuff' website. Using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.

I am not sure if the problem is to do with my install location of Python itself.
I have followed [this post](http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=16794) but when following the Environment element of the instructions the Python path isn't showing and I can't add the Python path (unsure as to why).

Python seems to be located at C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6

If I try and install pyperclip using `pip` in PowerShell I get the error message "No module named site". I have also tried following various other instructions in order to tell PowerShell where Python is located, but to no avail.

Comment: If it doesn't work out, you can always try an [anaconda python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) installation. It will simplify a lot of installation issues.

Comment: If you expect us to help, you need to *show* us what exactly you're doing, and what the results are. One thing I can tell you right away is that your Python installation is most likely not located in your start menu.

Comment: What is the command you are trying to run?  What do you get if you type "path" into a command prompt.

Comment: No, it isn't located in the Start Menu, not sure why I have copied that as my pathway. Will get some images of what is going on.

Comment: If I type "path" into Powershell I get Windows PowerShell


"path : The term 'path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ path
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (path:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

Comment: There is no `path` command in PowerShell. If you want to check the `PATH` environment variable you'd do it like this: `$env:PATH`. Also, please [edit] your question if you need to provide additional information.

Comment: I got this to work but downloading Anaconda and using the conda install in Powershell.